# Midi machine control specification

Tags: synchronization, protocols, midi, specifications

I'm trying to implement the MIDI machine control protocol but I'm unable to find the full specification...

I have found:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_Machine_Control
- http://www.somascape.org/midi/tech/spec.html#rusx_mmcc (containing the same information than wikipedia).
- http://madamebutterface.com/assets/documents/MIDI%201.0%20Detailed%20Specification.pdf

The last document refers to the "separate MMC Detailed Specification for complete details", but I am unable to find it.

Any idea?

Comment: Found this: http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/mmc.htm

Comment: Thanks! I found this link to but there is less information than wikipedia...

Answer (score 1):

The [MMA](http://www.midi.org) website is the source for MIDI documentation - they charge (£50 isn) for the protocol.
I would love a PDF version too but MMA do not do one.

It is very comprehensive - got mine back in 1986!

[Graham Hinton](http://www.hinton-instruments.co.uk/reference/midi/protocol/index.htm) has some good history but you only can find bits & pieces on the web

Good luck

Comment: here is a **little** more in a Roland PDF http://media.rolandus.com/manuals/CDX-1_MI.pdf